# Know type of entity by eyetrace

Tags: garrys-mod

How can a know an entity before me by GetEyeTrace. I want to check this and if entity == Weapon then do anything...

Whatever like below:

```
if ply:GetEyeTrace().Entity.IsWeapon() then
        print("+")
    end
```

But IsWeapon() function have no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :IsWeapon()

You should also really be checking if the entity is valid.

```
local ent = ply:GetEyeTrace().Entity
if(!IsValid(ent)) then return end 
if(ent:IsWeapon()) then
    print("This is a weapon.")
end
```